# Flutter - I want to know how to extract certain sentences from long characters into regex

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I want to extract the sentence I want from the long sentence.
Also, I want to know how to use **regular expressions**.

For example,

```
sdlkfjklsdjf lds \@test text@\ slkdjflksdjf
```

I want to extract `"test text"`, a sentence that starts with \@ and ends with @\ in the above sentence.

I tried to use lookahead and lookbehind, but I failed.
Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't support look behinds.

Instead, capture your target in a group:

```
final innerString = RegExp(r'\\@(.*)@\\').firstMatch(str)?.group(1);
```

---

Runnable code:

```dart
void main() {
  final str = "sdlkfjklsdjf lds \\@test text@\\ slkdjflksdjf";
  final innerString = RegExp(r'\\@(.*)@\\').firstMatch(str)?.group(1);
  print(innerString);
}
```

Output:

```
test text
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```dart
String str = "sdlkfjklsdjf lds \@test text@\ slkdjflksdjf";
final startIndex = str.indexOf("\@");
  final endIndex = str.indexOf("@\", startIndex + "/@".length);

  print(str.substring(startIndex + "/@".length, endIndex)); 
}
```